# How to access FormControl value in the HTML Code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am programmatically changing the value of the form "select".

In the form field, you can see that the value has changed. But the element `"p"` is still hidden.

If you manually change the value of the form, the visibility of the element "p" will work correctly.

> Expected Result:

```
The <p> tag should be visible if the value of `field1` FormControl is equal to `1`.
```

Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-form-field class="mb-4" fxFlex="100">
      <mat-select #field1 formControlName="field1" placeholder="Data type" required>
        <mat-option value="0" selected>Boolean</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="1">Int</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="2">Double</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="3">String</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="4">Byte array</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="5">Object</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>

<p *ngIf="field1.value === '1'">Integer</p>

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onClick()">Set 'Int'</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
export interface Item {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  public data: Item[] = [
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'Option 1'},
    {value: '2', viewValue: 'Option 2'},
    {value: '3', viewValue: 'Option 3'}
  ];
  public formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      field1: [1, null]
    });
  }

  onClick(){
    this.formGroup.controls.field1.setValue('1');
  }
}
```

[Example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrbfff?file=app/select-overview-example.html)

Comment: What do you want? the `<p>` should be visible on button click?

Comment: you can use: `formGroup.value.field1 === '1'`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Binding to the form works, I checked it. I can not understand why the binding to the mat-select element does not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead [`#template reference`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) variable, you can use:

```
formGroup.controls['field1'].value
```

so the HTML Code:

```
<p *ngIf="formGroup.controls['field1'].value === '1'">Integer</p>
```